# Calculate SD of SHAP values by using nested cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, standard-deviation, shapley-value

I follow a procedure as described in this paper (https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/12/13/6681). Thus, I calculate separate SHAP values for the training and test sets within each outer fold across multiple data partitions in a nested cross-validation scheme. Then, these SHAP values are averaged across outer folds and data partitions.
In the paper, they don't say something about the dispersion of the SHAP values. Would it be valid to calculate a standard devivation for the SHAP values based on the single estimates from the outer folds and the differennt data partitions?

Greetings,
Ole